# Creating a gradient area graph similar to the great acceleration graphs with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I use this code:

```
structure(list(Num = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
5, 5), name = c("env_data_1", "env_data_2", "env_data_3", "env_data_1", 
"env_data_2", "env_data_3", "env_data_1", "env_data_2", "env_data_3", 
"env_data_1", "env_data_2", "env_data_3", "env_data_1", "env_data_2", 
"env_data_3"), value = c(2.71828182845905, 5.43656365691809, 
18.1548454853771, 7.38905609893065, 14.7781121978613, 25.1671682967919, 
20.0855369231877, 40.1710738463753, 62.256610769563, 54.5981500331442, 
109.196300066288, 164.794450099433, 148.413159102577, 296.826318205153, 
455.23947730773)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))

env_data |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = Num, y = value, fill = value)) +
  geom_area() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_y")
```

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image: great acceleration graphs]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no native smooth-gradient fill of polygons or rectangles in ggplot. There are extension packages that allow this, such as `ggpattern`, but to preserve complete control and precise aesthetic mapping I normally use interpolation of the input values with very thin columns to achieve the effect:

```r
library(tidyverse)

env_data %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  reframe(value = approx(Num, value, xout = seq(1, 5, 0.01))$y,
          Num = seq(1, 5, 0.01)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Num, y = value, fill = value)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.01) +
  geom_line(col = '#39599c') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 4, linetype = 2, color = 'gray50') +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "#1c7bc4") +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_y") +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = 'gray50'),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I really like the look you made! Is it possible that the gradient changes according to the max value of each env_data? I think now the gradient in env_data_1 is dependent on the max value in the env_data_3. Is it possible to make them independent?

Comment: @RobinLindström you can set `fill = Num` to make the gradient change according to the x axis value. Since this is the same in each plot, the gradient will be the same too